# Checkbox menu items in wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I Have a subclass of `wx.Frame` in which I have constructed a fully functioning editor with a menu and multiline text input. I next need to create a checkbox menu item inside a menu created with this code:

```
self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
self.menuBar.Append(self.viewMenu, "&View")
self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
```

Using this code:

```
self.HideToolbarMenuItem = self.viewMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Hide Toolbar", self.HideToolbarHelp, kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
```

How do I add event handling to it or get it's value (`True` or `False`)? I am not interested yet in how to hide the toolbar.

**EDIT:** The menu does show the checkbox, and it can be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.HideToolbarMenuItem.IsChecked()` and a normal event handler. Example:

```
def OnBoxChecked(self, event):
    if self.HideToolbarMenuItem.IsChecked():
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Checked')
    else:
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Not Checked')
```